# Is it possible to have static constexpr fields in a private inner class?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, inner-classes

I have a C++14 project and cannot use C++17 inline variables.

```
// myclass.h
class MyClass {
  struct Inner {
    using StringArray = std::array<const char*, 1>;
    static constexpr StringArray kStrings{{ "foo" }};
  }
}

//myclass.cpp
constexpr MyClass::Inner::StringArray kStrings;
//                 ^^^^^                   
// Error: "Inner" is a private member of "MyClass"
```

Is it possible to get this to work in C++14, or will this only work in C++17?

Comment: Why not just remove the redeclaration? Isn't the inline initialization you have enough?

Comment: @Ted only when marked as `inline static constexpr` which is available starting with C++17. In C++14 I have to provide an out-of-class definition for such fields.

Comment: I mean like this: https://godbolt.org/z/qo6vedqfY

Comment: Interesting, but this still doesn't work for my use case: https://godbolt.org/z/jz1Kroaz1

Comment: You haven't created an instance of `Inner` in your usecase but I get your point

Comment: That's why I need it to be static. -- But it was all a minor error anyway and of course it works with Artyer's answer :)

Comment: Got it! ...and Artyer got my vote too!

Comment: A point about terminology: Java provides a magical relationship between "outer" and "inner" classes. C++ doesn't do that; there's no special relationship between objects of a nested type and objects of the containing type. So the usual term for a nested class is "nested class", not "inner class".

Comment: @TedLyngmo (and OP): With C++17 it is possible to mark the member `inline`, however `constexpr` static members are implicitly `inline` starting with C++17, so that is redundant. The original would work without the redeclaration in C++17 as you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your trying to give a definition for a new file-scope variable called `::kStrings`. You want to define the static member `MyClass::Inner::kStrings` instead:

```cpp
constexpr MyClass::Inner::StringArray MyClass::Inner::kStrings;
```